# Redirigir a un archivo en Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel-8, redirección, blade, qr

Tengo el siguiente problema, y es que necesito redirigir desde un enlace el cual es creado por mi con 6 caracteres aleatorios para hacer de acortador hacia un archivo. El problema es que, cuando intento acceder al archivo me pone la url http://127.0.0.1:8000/C:/Users/miUsuario/Escritorio/proyecto/public/assets/PDFs/archivo.pdf pero yo no necesito esta url, sino lo siguiente, que sería a partir de C://

Mi duda es, cómo podría hacer esto? Ya que no encuentro nada que me lo pueda solucionar y llevo días intentando dar con el problema e intentándolo de otras formas, incluso con:

```
Storage::disk('local')->get($qr->documento)
```

El código del blade es el siguiente:

```
 <a class="button shortlink" href="{{ route('acortar.linkDocumento', $qr->codigo) }}" target="_blank"> <i class="fa fa-link"></i>
    {{ route('acortar.linkDocumento', $qr->codigo) }} </a> <br>
```

Donde pone `$qr->codigo` son los 6 caracteres aleatorios generados para hacer de acortador y redireccionador. La ruta de  `acortar.linkDocumento` se encuentra en Web, y es la siguiente:

```
Route::get('Pdf/{codigo}', '\App\Http\Controllers\QrController@acortarLinkDocumento')->name('acortar.linkDocumento');
```

El método al que hace referencia del controlador es el siguiente:

```
    public function acortarLinkDocumento($codigo)
{
    $find = Qr::where('codigo', $codigo)->first();

    return redirect($find->documento);
}
```

**PD:** En $qr->documento se guarda la ruta absoluta a partir de C://

Espero vuestra ayuda y muchas gracias si habéis llegado a leer todo.

Answer (score 0):

Aquí obtienes esa ruta? . `$qr->documento`.
Estudia como se usa `substr`.

```
$start =4;
$ruta-que-quiero = substr($qr->documento,$start);
```

Pd: si no pones fin según la doc va hasta el final de la cadena de texto.